# How to ignore rows of common value, if there's a NULL in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling with writing a statement that would query for both:

- all rows of one common id, which never have `NULL`s in *two other columns*
- just those rows of one common id, which if there is a `NULL` in either of two other columns, query for records with a date greater or equal than the last record having a `NULL` in either of *two columns*

An example with sample data (those 'two columns' here are `old_param` and `new_param`);
+**empty strings are considered equivalent to NULL** for the software using this DB:

[image: example result set to work on]

- Colored in green are rows that the query should return.
- all rows of `objid` 5 and 4 should **be included**, since both `old_param` and `new_param` never have `NULL`s occurring.
- from rows of `objid` 6 - row #6 since it's the **latest occurrence** of either of `new_param` or `old_param` **being `NULL`**, so the older ones should be ignored, but the consecutive ones occurring after this row should be included.

I was thinking of splitting those two conditions into two separate queries joined by a UNION to make the task easier, but I am unsure of how to write a query that would separate those conditions by the id column.

I did, however, manage to write a query for the second of my requirements:

```
SELECT {various columns}
  FROM {table name + joins}
  WHERE [date] >= (
                SELECT MAX([date]) 
                FROM {table name}
                WHERE [new_param] IS NOT NULL 
                    AND ([old_param] IS NULL 
                         OR DATALENGTH([old_param]) = 0))
```

But I can't figure out how to combine it into one, bigger query.

Comment: *"I can't embed images in my posts yet, sorry!"* Don't use images at all. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to supply sample data, then please use DDL and DML statements. If you want to provide expected results, use a markdown table.

Comment: _never have NULLs occurring_ But your image of SSMS output suggests you don't have NULL values at all. So the first step is to **know** what your data is and how to filter out the rows you do not want.  _all rows of objid 5 and 4_ You have only one of each - that isn't helpful to understand your logic.

Comment: @SMor You are correct; For my case, NULLs and empty strings mean the same thing for the software using this DB. I edited my question to add that remark. Adding "or empty string" to every mention of NULL caused a lot of bloat, so I decided against it.

Comment: As for objid 4 and 5 - I assumed that all other rows of these ids would not contain empty strings/nulls anywhere else. And as such, all their rows should be included. I should've made that more clear, my bad. Not sure how else to explain that without adding more example data though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Data to work with
DECLARE @data TABLE (date date, new_param nvarchar(100), objid int, old_param nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-10', 'hello', 5, 'world')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-10', 'hello', 4, 'world')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-11', 'hello', 6, '')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-12', 'hello', 6, 'world')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-13', '', 6, 'world')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-14', 'hello', 6, '')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-15', 'hello', 6, 'world')
INSERT INTO @data (date, new_param, objid, old_param) VALUES ('2022-08-16', 'hello', 6, 'world')


--The query you are looking for
SELECT date, new_param, objid, old_param
FROM @data d
WHERE date >= ISNULL((SELECT MAX(date) 
                      FROM @data  
                      WHERE objid = d.objid 
                          and (ISNULL(new_param, '') = '' or ISNULL(old_param, '') = '')), date)
```

The subquery gets the maximum date where one of the params is null for each `objid`, if there are no such entries the subquery will return null which is then checked by the `ISNULL` condition and takes the right date. This is the result I'm getting from what I understood from the question.

[image]

Comment: I managed to generate more data today and this works like a charm. I did, however, just notice that my sample query from the main post differs from what I tried to explain (new_param should have data, old_param not). Your query works for my data set nevertheless. Should the need arise to change those conditions, I should be good to go with your query. I wouldn't have figured it out though on my own, so thank you very much!